# Convert polylines to renderable shape

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to take an array of GPS points and convert it to some sort of drawable shape, for example a `UIBezierPath` or `CGPath`? If not, can someone point me in the right direction of a perhaps a third-party library or similar? I don't mean on a map, I mean on a regular UIView.

A way I can think of is first drawing it on a MKMapView and then some how extrapolating that shape?

**Edit**: By poly line it mean an array of GPS coordinates.

Comment: Since a gps coordinate is just a point, yes, you can convert an array of cps coordinates and turn it into a CGPath (or UIRenderPath)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use `UIBezierPath` for draw polyline inside `UIView` by overriding `drawRect:` method. read the detail reference on apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html